# "Пригоди Аліси в країні чудес" чи "Алісині пригоди у Дивокраї"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Відома книга  *"Alice's Adventures in Wonderland"* (Lewis Carroll).

Як правильно зробити переклад назви книги *"Пригоди Аліси в країні чудес"* чи *"Алісині пригоди у Дивокраї"*?

Зустрічала обидва варіанти - *["Пригоди Аліси в країні чудес"](http://ukrbooks.com/ua/alisa_v_kraini_chudes/)* та *["Алісині пригоди у Дивокраї"](https://bookland.com/download/1/11/115384/sample.pdf)*. Зокрема в одній статті [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%83_%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97) присутні два варіанти.

В СУМ-11 присутне слово [*чудесний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chudesnyj), але немає *чудеса* (чи я неправильно шукаю). Чи потрібно в назві книги слово *"чудес"* замінити на *"див"*?

Answer (score 3):

Назва книги "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland" написана у так званому Title Case, коли всі важливі слова пишуться з великої літери, тому з неї важко сказати, Wonderland - це власна назва, чи просто "типова країна див".

Але судячи з цієї [цитати](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-h/11-h.htm): "So she sat on, with closed eyes, and half believed herself in **Wonderland**, though she knew she had but to open them again, and all would change to dull reality <...>" Wonderland - все ж таки власна назва, отже її треба писати з великої літери.

Щодо перекладу власних назв - тут важко оцінювати чим "Дивокрай" правильніший за "країну чудес", можна лише оцінити чи відповідають вони нормам українського словотвору і т.і. (проте у загальному випадку навіть це може не бути критерієм, якщо оригінальний твір навмисне порушує правила, як, приміром, назва "Mortal Kombat").

(Можна тільки додати що словосполучення "країна чудес" не дуже схоже на назву країни, тому написання "Країна чудес" з великої літери може викликати подив у читача. Отже питання тут стоїть таким чином - перекладати власну назву як власну назву, чи використати "країну чудес" як означення цього дивного місця, тим більше що слово Wonderland у тексті зустрічається лише тричі - у назві книги та у двох останніх абзацах).

Дивокрай норми словотвору не порушує, а щодо "чудес", у СУМі є відповідна [стаття](http://sum.in.ua/s/chudo) (досить велика):

> ЧУ́ДО, а, мн. **чудеса**, сер.
>
> 1. За марновірними та релігійними уявленнями — явище, нібито викликане надприродними силами, чаклунством, втручанням божої сили. 
>      ♦ Чудеса в решеті див. решето; Чудо природи див. природа.
> 2. перен. Те, що гідне великого подиву, незвичайне, дивовижне.  <...>
> 3. <...>
>      ♦ Чудо з чудес — те, що особливо виділяється на фоні чого-небудь величного, гідного подиву. — Константинополь! Царев город! Царгород! Чудо з чудес! (Семен Скляренко, Святослав, 1959, 135).
> 4. <...>
>      ♦ Чудо-юдо, нар.-поет. — казкове чудовисько. [Парвус:] Так варті ж ви, щоб вас пожерли змії і люті чуда-юда океану! (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 353).

Comment: Так, погоджуюся. Для цих варіантів не можна сказати, що правильніше, — це просто різне бачення різними перекладачами.

Answer (score 2):

Кілька цитат з [підручника з порівняльного літературознавства Будного, Ільницького](http://megalib.com.ua/content/43_41_Pereklad_i_iogo_riznovidi.html), розділу про переклад:

Перша цитата:

> Мистецький (художній) переклад - це відтворення літературного тексту
>   засобами іншої мови **з якомога повнішим збереженням його мистецьких
>   якостей**.

Друга цитата:

> **Буквальний переклад**, навіть зі споріднених мов, практично неможливий,
>   бо точність передачі лексичних» синтаксичних, версифікаційних
>   особливостей оригіналу супроводжується *втратою важливих змістових
>   нюансів*, а дослівне калькування фразеологізмів призводить до комічних
>   ефектів. **Вільний переклад** використовує образні засоби, не властиві
>   першотворові, щоби відтворити його дух.

Третя цитата:

> Вважають, що **хороший переклад - це непомітний переклад,** інтерпретатор
>   повинен репрезентувати читачеві не себе, а автора.

Отже переклад має:

1. Якомога повніше зберігати мистецькі якості ориґіналу.
2. Якщо буквальний переклад цьому заважає - застосовується вільний переклад.
3. Хороший переклад має бути непомітним, не затуляти собою ориґіналу.

В ориґіналі маємо **Wonderland**. В перекладі: "**країна чудес**" або "**Дивокрай**".

Як на мене, мистецькі якості ориґіналу краще передає слово "Дивокрай", адже окремі слова "**диво**" і "**край**" точно відповідають англійським "**wonder**" і "**land**", і в назві залишається одне слово, а не створюється два, тобто, такий переклад **непомітніший**, аніж двослівний.

З іншого боку, світова традиція перекладу цієї назви така, що в багатьох мовах слово "Wonderland" перетворюють на два слова у назві (а це значить, що переклад у такий спосіб вже прижився у багатьох культурах, і нема підстав вважати, що він не приживеться в українській):

1. Чеська: "Alenka v **říši divů**".
2. Польська: "Alicja w **Krainie Czarów**".
3. Іспанська: "Las aventuras de Alicia en **el país de las maravillas**".
4. Французька: "Les Aventures d'Alice au **pays des merveilles**".
5. Тощо.

Втім, німці спокійно собі зробили свій відповідник одним словом (однак варто зазначити, що воно майже не відрізняється від англійського відповідника): "Alice im **Wunderland**".

Отже, хоч особисто мені більше подобається переклад одним словом (адже мистецькі якості й загальний сенс слова в ориґіналі не втрачаються), мушу визнати, що обидва варіанти мають право на існування, і зрештою усталиться той, що знайде більшу прихильність серед читачів, покупців книг, критиків, науковців тощо вкупі.

P.S. Сподіваюсь, це буде "Дивокрай")